# Javafx event handler overlap

Tags: javafx

I have a pane, inside the pane I have a circle and a label. Everytime mouse enter or exit the circle, the label will change to "enter" or "exit". And the label will move accordingly to the mouse position (mouse scenceX and sceneY).

The problem is when I enter the mouse inside the circle, the label will change to "enter" but will immediately change to "exit" then.

I think there is an overlap eventhandler somewhere in my code, but I don't know why. This is my code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey;");
        pane.setPrefSize(300,300);

        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        int radius = 50;
        circle.setRadius(radius);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        circle.setStrokeWidth(2);
        circle.setLayoutX(100);
        circle.setLayoutY(60);
        pane.getChildren().add(circle);

        Label label = new Label("Mouse point is outside the circle");
        pane.getChildren().add(label);

        circle.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, e -> {
            label.setText("Mouse point is outside the circle");
            System.out.println("exit");
        });
        circle.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, e -> {
            label.setText("Mouse point is inside the circle");
            System.out.println("enter");
        });
        pane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e -> {
            label.setLayoutX(e.getSceneX());
            label.setLayoutY(e.getSceneY());
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm only guessing but I believe the problem is that when the *event filter* for `pane` is executed, the result is that the mouse pointer moves from being inside `circle` to inside `label`. Then when you move the mouse, it leaves `label` and enters `circle` which causes the `MOUSE_ENTERED` event handler to fire. After that handler fires, the event filter fires which moves the mouse pointer out of `circle` and into `label` which causes `MOUSE_EXITED` event handler to fire. That's why you see *enter* and *exit* repeatedly when you move the mouse pointer around inside `circle`. You don't see *enter* nor *exit* at all when you move the mouse pointer around `pane` when it is outside of `circle`.

In order to fix it, I removed `MOUSE_ENTERED` and `MOUSE_EXITED` and inside the event filter, I check whether the mouse pointer is inside the bounds of `circle` and set `label` text accordingly.

Here is the code.
(Note that I replaced `addEventFilter` with `setOnMouseMoved`.)

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey;");
        pane.setPrefSize(300, 300);

        Label label = new Label("Mouse point is outside the circle");

        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        int radius = 50;
        circle.setRadius(radius);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        circle.setStrokeWidth(2);
        circle.setLayoutX(100);
        circle.setLayoutY(60);
        Bounds boundingBox = circle.getBoundsInParent();
        double maxX = boundingBox.getMaxX();
        double minX = boundingBox.getMinX();
        double maxY = boundingBox.getMaxY();
        double minY = boundingBox.getMinY();

        pane.getChildren().add(circle);
        pane.getChildren().add(label);
        pane.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
            double x = e.getSceneX();
            double y = e.getSceneY();
            if (minX < x && x < maxX && minY < y && y < maxY) {
                label.setText("Mouse point is inside the circle");
            }
            else {
                label.setText("Mouse point is outside the circle");
            }
            label.setLayoutX(e.getSceneX());
            label.setLayoutY(e.getSceneY());
        });
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: `label.setMouseTransparent(true)` doesn’t fix it?

Comment: That is exactly what is going on,Thanks you very much!
Another solution is setMouseTransparent on label

Answer (score 1):

As explained in another answer, when the label moves, it moves so that the mouse is now inside the label; this means it is no longer hovering directly over the circle, so an "exited" event is fired on the circle.

The simplest fix is just to make the label ignore the mouse, which can be done using the `mouseTransparent` property:

```
    Label label = new Label("Mouse point is outside the circle");
    label.setMouseTransparent(true);
    pane.getChildren().add(label);
```